# mySQL MAX() working from phpmyadmin but not from php script?

Tags: php, mysql, select, max

EDIT: SOLVED - As usual, the error code was unrelated to the suspect code.  I was using a variable in place of table_name and it was getting switched to the wrong table prior to running the query.

For anyone interested, all of the proposed solutions, as well as the original code, posted below, are now working for me.  Thanks for all the help!  Sorry for my idiocy.

ORIGINAL POST:
I have a strange error occurring.

I am trying to get the maximum value from a mysql database column into my php script using the following code:

```
$q = "SELECT MAX(item_id) AS maxid FROM table_name";
$q = mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $maxItemNum = $row['maxid'];
}
echo $maxItemNum;
```

However, the $maxItemNum that gets echoed is a count of the table rows rather than the maximum value from the 'item_id' column.

The strange thing is, when I run the following command via phpmyadmin, I get the proper result (225):

```
SELECT MAX(item_id) FROM table_name
```

Any ideas as to the issue?  I'm stumped...

Comment: if that's an auto_increment field, and you DON'T delete older records, then max(id) tends to be the same-ish value as count(id) anyways.

Comment: @MarcB The item_id field is not an auto_increment field..  Still no idea as to why phpmyadmin would give me the correct value but the php script is not..

Comment: Did you use `$maxItemNum` earlier in the code? If this query failed due to a bad `table_name` or something, it would still be holding onto an earlier value.

Comment: @Michael - Negative, set the variable to zero prior to running the above code and got the same error. :-/

Comment: try $makItemNum = 0; just before "while" line

Comment: simply try once using `SELECT count(item_id) AS maxid FROM table_name`

Comment: @oz, as I said above, already tried setting $makeItemNum=0; prior to running the query, also, tried your second suggestion echo $maxItemNum = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(item_id) AS maxid FROM table_name LIMIT 1"),0); and got the same error, a count of all the rows rather than the MAXIMUM value from the item_id column

Comment: @Maulik, COUNT() returned the same value as MAX(), it seems that COUNT() is working properly..

Comment: try it like this then ("SELECT item_id AS maxid FROM table_name ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $maxItemNum = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(item_id) AS maxid FROM table_name LIMIT 1"),0);
```

One line is good! At least for this (:

Comment: NO-ONE-LINE-IS-NOT-GOOD!  Never a good idea to nest `mysql_query()` inside `mysql_result()`. If the query fails, `mysql_result()` gets an invalid resource and you have a errors reported.

Comment: Are you sure there is a field in your table named "item_id"?

Comment: @oz, marked as the solution even though my original code did the trick once the proper table was selected *duh*

Answer (score 0):

And this:

```
$q = "SELECT max(item_id) AS max_value FROM table_name";
$q = mysqli_query($q);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q) ; //just one set of data
$maxItemNum = $row['max_value'];

echo $maxItemNum;
```

It's working for me....tested on wamp 2.2.

Saludos ;)